# How to randomly extract a value N time in Python?

Tags: python, random

In order to program a TMS experiment, I need to randomly extract a number from a list of three values, each of one for 8 times. So I will have 24 trials, 8 of which  with myvar = 1, 8 with myvar=2 and 8 with myvar=3. But after I run the experiment, the output shows that the three values were picked non-equally.
How can I fix it?

My code is:

```
global io #TMS settings
trigger = 255
port = 0x378

lst = (1,2,3)
import random
x = random.choices(lst,k=1)
myvar = x

try:
    self.sleep(myvar)
    io.DlPortWritePortUchar(port, trigger)
    self.sleep(1)
    io.DlPortWritePortUchar(port, 0)
except:
    print('Failed to send trigger!')
```

Comment: Depending on how many times you run, they will indeed not have been chosen an equal number of times.  You would have to run a very large number of times in order for it to be exactly equally distributed.

Comment: Also, you might wanna consider cleaning up your example a little bit here. For instance, you could eliminate `x` from your code, simply by replacing the line where you get the choices with `myvar = random.choices(lst, k=1)`.

Comment: I ran the entire experiment (432 trials!) but I still have the same problem. I don't figure out how to have the same number of myvar1, myvar2 and myvar3.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
>>> from random import choices
>>> lst = (1,2,3)
>>> choices(lst, k=24)
[2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: I think that the original question is about not having the same number of events for each choice, so even this example wouldn't solve the problem. Albeit, it is a very elegant way of writing the code.